# Execution failed for task ':cloud_firestore:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: flutter, gradle, dart, build.gradle

My Apologies for asking the question which has been already asked, the reason is I didn't get it,
can anyone help me with this

here is the exception I got
Execution failed for task ':cloud_firestore:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
and  app is unable to run emulator

```
D:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.8.2+3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java:274: error: cannot find symbole\CloudFirestorePlugin.java:8: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
                                 ^
D:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.8.2+3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java:272: error: cannot find symbole\CloudFirestorePlugin.java:9: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
                                 ^
D:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.8.2+3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java:503: error: cannot find symbole\CloudFirestorePlugin.java:253: error: cannot find symbol
          public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                 ^
  symbol: class NonNull                                                                                                              e\CloudFirestorePlugin.java:558: error: cannot find symbol
D:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.8.2+3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java:274: error: cannot find symbol
                    public Void apply(@NonNull Transaction transaction)
                                       ^
  symbol: class NonNull
D:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.8.2+3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java:272: error: cannot find symbol
                    @Nullable
                     ^
  symbol: class Nullable
D:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.8.2+3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java:503: error: cannot find symbol
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {                                                                     full insights.
                                           ^
  symbol: class NonNull
D:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.8.2+3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java:558: error: cannot find symbol
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                           ^
  symbol: class NonNull                                    
7 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':cloud_firestore:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.


BUILD FAILED in 5s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         6.3s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin cloud_firestore...
The plugin cloud_firestore could not be built due to the issue above.
```

below are dependencies and plugins in the app/build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.smile"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
}
```

below are dependencies in andriod/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

The dependencies in pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  carousel_pro: ^1.0.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.6.6 
  cloud_firestore: any
  google_sign_in: ^4.1.4
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.6+2
  fluttertoast: ^3.1.3
  provider: 3.0.0
  flutter_svg: ^0.17.3+1
```

Comment: change from any to cloud_firestore: ^0.13.4+2 @vinny

Comment: I tried with your suggestion but I got a new error which I mentioned below @jose Praveen

Comment: Because cloud_firestore >=0.13.3 depends on firebase_core ^0.4.4 and firebase_auth 0.6.6 depends on firebase_core ^0.2.5+1, cloud_firestore >=0.13.3 is incompatible with firebase_auth 0.6.6.
And because no versions of firebase_auth match >0.6.6 <0.7.0, cloud_firestore >=0.13.3 is incompatible with firebase_auth ^0.6.6.
So, because smile depends on both firebase_auth ^0.6.6 and cloud_firestore ^0.13.4+2, version solving failed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing the [firebase_core](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core) plugin, which is an essential package to use Firebase Core API.

Check [this documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/core/usage/) for more info on using Firebase in Flutter.

Another possible reason could be the version of your `cloud_firestore` plugin, it might be conflicting with other dependencies. Use the latest version of your packages (e.g. [`cloud_firestore 3.1.0`](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore)) and on your app/build.gradle, update the `minSdkVersion 16` to `minSdkVersion 23` as mentioned in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61185707/flutter-firebase-build-failed-cloud-firestorecompiledebugjavawithjavac).