# Flutter-Firebase Build Failed ':cloud_firestore:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

I've just started learning flutter and firebase. I'm following this tutorial [https://grokonez.com/android/how-to-integrate-flutter-firebase-tutorial-app-android-studio], did everything as mentioned, but app is not being built successfully. This is the error I'm having:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi 6 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Note: D:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.2.5+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FirebaseCorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
D:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.7.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java:8: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
                                 ^
D:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.7.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java:9: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
                                 ^
D:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.7.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java:248: error: cannot find symbol
          public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                 ^
  symbol: class NonNull
D:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.7.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java:269: error: cannot find symbol
                    public Void apply(@NonNull Transaction transaction)
                                       ^
  symbol: class NonNull
D:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.7.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java:267: error: cannot find symbol
                    @Nullable
                     ^
  symbol: class Nullable
D:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.7.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java:495: error: cannot find symbol
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                           ^
  symbol: class NonNull
D:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.7.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java:548: error: cannot find symbol
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                           ^
  symbol: class NonNull
Note: D:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.7.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
7 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':cloud_firestore:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 58s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin cloud_firestore...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
Finished with error: The plugin cloud_firestore could not be built due to the issue above.
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.testflutter.flutterfirebase"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

**android\build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3' // new
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()


    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
name: flutterfirebase
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter



  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

  cloud_firestore: ^0.7.4

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Anybody can help how to fix this? Have already been searching for hours. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update the `minSdkVersion`:

```
minSdkVersion 16
```

Into:

```
minSdkVersion 23
```

Comment: did you update it inside `app/build.gradle`? Also add your pubspec.yaml file

Comment: Yes, updated inside app/build.gradle. 
Added pubspec.yaml

Comment: use the following firestore version `cloud_firestore: ^0.13.4+2`

Comment: Yes, after updating & running packages get, the issue is resolved. Thanks a lot.